# Trying to put a button within a anchor tag

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a list app and I'm and trying to add a remove button, so that you can remove lists and list items.

My question is, how do I add this button within a list item? I want the whole list item to be clickable, but when I press the span element i don't want the anchor tag to activate, only the ng-click event.

```
<div class="list-group">
    <a href="#/list" class="list-group-item">
        {{listName}}
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove pull-right" ng-click="delete()"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

I'm using bootstrap, feel free to suggest other ways to add this remove button.

Comment: Doe it have to be a anchor tag ? it just seems the anchor takes you nowhere, not even an page anchor #id If it has to be a a tag put an onclick on it <a href="javascript:void(0)" >

Comment: @Billy I shortended the link to make it less confusing for people who aren't using angular. It looks like this in my code "#/list/{{listDetails.id}}"

Comment: Can you use js or jquery to disable the click? or put an onclick on the a tag to disable it ? onclick="return false;"

Answer (score 0):

You Can add this `JQuery` code:

```js
$(a).click(function(){ return false;});
```

Comment: I still want to be able to click the link. I just don't want the link to activate when I press the span element. I guess this might be an issue with angular.